# How can I create an alert Dialog window with a seek bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following layout :

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="20"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:progressDrawable="@android:color/white"
    android:thumb="@drawable/drunk"
    />
```

this declared outside the Alert dialog

```
private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener customSeekBarListener = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Progress is " + progress);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    } ;
```

and this is the alert dialog which happens when I click a button (edited)

```
public void press(){
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seekbar, null);
   SeekBar mySeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
   mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);
  // final EditText input = new EditText(this);
  // input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER );

    AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   //LayoutInflater inflater = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
   myAlert.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name,null))
            .setView(mView)
            .setMessage("SeekBar")
            .setTitle("title")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .create();
    myAlert.show();
}
```

I am sure that I'm missing something because it doesn't work. How can I fix it ? I'm using android-studio.

The error that I'm getting now is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at projectName.MainActivity.press(MainActivity.java:109)
```

and that line is `mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);`

Comment: What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I get an error on ' mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);'. It says that is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First inflate the view you want to set to dialog with `LayoutInflater`:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, null);
```

Than initialize your seekbar:

```
SeekBar mySeekBar = (SeekBar) mView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);
```

Set your dialogs view to view you inflated:

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
myAlert.setMessage("SeekBar")
        .setView(mView)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .create();
myAlert.show();
```

Hope it helps and happy coding !

Comment: I will try that now :D. Do I have to create a dialog_view now ? I don't have one at the moment.

Comment: I recommend creating your dialog's view in a separate xml :)

Comment: I did it your way but now I get an error with 'mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(customSeekBarListener);'

Answer (score 0):

You need to inflate your layout.

`SeekBar mySeekBar  = (SeekBar) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mySeekBar, null);`

Comment: That won't work. I get this : 'android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.SeekBar'

Comment: Is the seekbar the only thing in your layout? Your line of `.setView(mySeekBar)` makes me think so. If you change the seekbar to the root element, then it would work.

Comment: What do you mean by changing it to the root element?

Comment: `android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.SeekBar` means that LinearLayout is your root element. If your layout only contains a SeekBar, then it would be your root element.

Comment: yes, the seekBar is the only element. What do you say that I should do ?

Comment: Could you take a look at the errors that I'm gettint now ?

Comment: if you are going with Melihcan's solution, you need to call `findViewById` on your view, ie. `SeekBar mySeekBar = (SeekBar) mView.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);`

Comment: that solved the problem, thank you.  I really appreciate your help.. but now I don't know which answer to accept

Comment: You should probably accept his, since you used it. And upvote mine.